# expressjs saving/updating data on mongoDB without rendering anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'd like to save and/or update objects in mongoDB without re-rendering the page but just retrieving the success or not of the post function because the front end is already updated after users' actions. Old skool stuff, ok.

Server side POST req:

```
exports.project_update_post = [

// some stuff ...

// Validate / Sanitize fields.
// ...


// Process request after validation and sanitization.
(req, res, next) => {


    // Extract the validation errors from a request.
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    // Create a Project object with escaped/trimmed data and old id.
    var project = new Project(
      { 
        name: req.body.name,
        //data: dataobj, // ???
        _id: req.params.id
       });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        
        // ...
        
    }
    else {
        // Data from form is valid. Update the record.
        Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, project, {}, function (err, theproject) {
            if (err) { 
                return next(err); 
            }
            // Successful
            //res...what ?
           
            
        });
    }
}
];
```

Front-end code (a JS module loaded in the HTML page, JQuery injecting stuff in a pug file):

```
var projectData;

export function init(prj){
    projectData = prj;

    let vidcont = $('<div id="tmp-vidcol" class="win-shadow">'+ projectData.data[0].boxtype   +'</div>')
    vidcont.css({ 'width':853, 'height':480, 'background': Skin.window.backgroundColor })
    
    let form = $('<form method="POST" action=""></form')
    let prjname = $('<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="'+ projectData.name  +'"></input>')
    form.append(prjname)
    /* let hidd = $('<input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="'+ projectData.data +'">')
    form.append(hidd) */
    let btn = $('<button type="submit">SAVE</button>') 
    form.append(btn)
    
    vidcont.append(form)
    mainDiv.append(vidcont)

}
window.init = init
```

The code is saving properly. What I can't achieve is to stay on the page without re-render it, because all the fields are already showing the inputted values. I'd like to show a modal instead, like "Yeah, saved". Kind of.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `res.redirect()`, you can use `res.json()` or `res.send()`, this won't redirect or render a new page.

Try this:

```
Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, project, {}, function (err, theproject) {
   if (err) { return next(err); }
   res.send(theproject.url);
});
```

Read more about [res.send()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) and [res.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) for more info.

Comment: clearly, res.send() send me to the string /projects/5f66197etc uhm... not working for my need. But thank you.

Comment: `res.send` wont redirect to any page, or reload the page, but it all depends on how you are using the post call.

Comment: you are absolutely right Ravi. I still don't understand how to handle the response on the front-end javascript... It was simple in my PHP MySQL days :)  It's all day I'm trying to figure it out. Any suggestion welcome (Axios, Ajax? ... )

Comment: shankar I've found my solution: Axios :)